# PostgreSQL set a table age based on a date

Tags: postgresql, date, triggers, psql

I've run into a problem with my postgreSQL database.  I have a table with a name, date of birth, and age.

```
    CREATE TABLE guy
        (name       VARCHAR(10),
         dob        DATE,
         age        INTEGER,
         PRIMARY KEY (name)
         );
```

What I want it to do is when I insert a new guy, I want the age to automatically be the age.

```
INSERT INTO guy VALUES ('Bill', '05-02-1992');
```

and have the age automatically be 21.

I don't know if I need a trigger to do this or if there is something I can do in the DDL.

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a trigger to calculate that during insertion time.

The drawback of that solution is that you would need to update the table each and every year - or actually every day in a year that has one row with that date as the date of birth to keep the age column "up-to-date".

Usually it's not a good idea to store information that can easily be derived from the existing data (especially if it's that cheap to calculate).

You can create a view that returns the information on the the fly based on the following select:

```
select name,
       dob,
       age(dob) as age
from guy;
```

That will always show up-to-date information without the need to ever update the data in the table.